# Is this garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I'm sure something similar has been asked before, but the sheer number of similar questions that don't answer my question force me to ask for myself.

Say you have the following code:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var somearray=[1, 2, 3];
    for(var i=0; i<somearray.length; i++) {
        //do something
        }
    function loop() {
        //do something repeatedly
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }
    loop();
    })();
```

Since the variable `i` is defined in the same scope as a perpetual loop, does it continue to exist even if unused, waiting for the possibility that it may be used eventually? Or is JavaScript's (particularly Chrome's V8) garbage collector smart enough to determine whether it will be used or not?

I know that I can add `console.log(i)` to the loop somewhere and then `i` will continue to exist so long as it's referenced, but will it continue to exist unreferenced in a scope that continues to exist?

Comment: Does the "do something repeatedly" code *reference* the "somearray" variable or not?  If it doesn't, it's (probably) garbage-collected.

Comment: Do you mean the `i` variable or the array, *"add console.log(i) to the loop somewhere and then i will continue to exist"*, implies that it's the `i` variable, but asking about the array seems to make more sense ?

Comment: I'm asking if it is (for certain) garbage collected if it is unreferenced ("will it continue to exist unreferenced in a scope that continues to exist?") - because the scope doesn't go away, I'm curious whether the scope-defined variable does. This question addresses that "probably" in your comment. Edit: Also, I'm referring to the `i` variable as adeneo states, thanks.

Comment: If the "loop" function declares its own "i" or "somearray" variables, or simply does not reference those, then it's probably safe to assume that a modern JavaScript runtime will be able to collect that space. **There are no guarantees.** It's a dynamic language and garbage collection is not a detectable activity (except through external tools).

Comment: I'm hoping some witty fellow on this site has a guarantee.

Comment: for loops doesn't have a special scope, so the i variable is available as long as you're in the scope of the outer IIFE, and can't be collected until after that has finished (at the earliest), which should include the loop function with the lower scope.

Comment: @fay—garbage collection is entirely implementation dependent, ECMA-262 just provies minimal requirements for when things are available for collection, it doesn't go into detail. So only someone familiar with the inner workings of a particular implementation can give you a definitive answer (and only for that particular implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not really a question about the garbage collector rather it is question about whether the closure is optimized. The closure optimizer of the execution environment might determine that the variables are not referenced (closed over) by the nested functions and then elide them from the closure environment. If that is the case, then they are candidates for collection. If the closure optimizer isn't run, or it determines `i` and `somearray` are referenced, or it cannot determine the lifetime of `i` and `somearray`, then they will not be collected as they are required by the closure environment.

A function has an implicit environment which includes all local variables in the enclosing function (and all functions enclosing it). This environment will capture any objects referenced by those variables. A closure optimizer statically analyzes the function to determine if the environment can be trimmed to elide the unreferenced variables. If the variables are elided from the environment they are candidates for collection as soon as the function invocation is concluded.

All modern JavaScript engines have a closure optimizer.

Some common things that might disable or limit the closure optimizer include being in a debug mode, using direct `eval()`, use of the `arguments` array, use of deprecated features such as `caller`.

As you can see, it clearly depends on what `\\do something repeatedly` does and in what context the code is executed in.

One way to ensure that they are not captured regardless of what `\\do something repeatedly` does is to ensure they are no longer in scope. An immediately executing function will do just that so changing your code to,

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  (function() {
    var somearray=[1, 2, 3];
    for(var i=0; i<somearray.length; i++) {
      //do something
    }
   })();
  function loop() {
    //do something repeatedly
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  loop();
})();
```

will ensure the array is not left hanging around in memory.

Comment: A named function expression should be available as an enhancement: `(function loop(){requestAnimationFrame(loop)}());` but not sure if that's OK with IE these days.

Comment: This works in IE 9 and greater as it is part of the ECMA spec.

Comment: Not all browsers follow the spec. Some [versions of IE](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs) have issues with named function expressions.

Comment: I agree which is why I qualified my answer by version number. Starting with IE 9, IE follows the ECMA spec. The referenced page is describing pre-IE 9 behavior that is still supported by IE 9-11 but only under compatibility and quirks modes.

Comment: I know another IIFE is a solution, but it would've been nice to know an unnecessary one. Unfortunately a quick check using `eval()` confirms `i` exists unreferenced, which is a shame but I suppose JS has to be ready for anything even if it leaves loose ends. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @RobG Off-topic, but that's a much cleaner way to go about it, thanks for the extra nugget of knowledge

Comment: @fay Using `eval()` is not a good test. It actually causes `i` to be captured where it might normally not be captured.